# Dump all databases and reimport on another server?

Tags: mysql

It's quite simple really, I just can't figure out the syntax.

I want to replicate my server setup on another server.

I can dump all my databases with

```
mysqldump -uroot -p --alldatabases > all.sql
```

But how do I import ALL of those into a brand new mysql setup on another server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if the database servers are both near enough the same version, you could simply rsync the /var/lib/mysql directory over.

`rsync /var/lib/mysql root@destination.server.com:/var/lib/ -a`

Edit: Please note that there are some issues with this approach which require some additional steps:
http://verens.com/2016/05/11/quick-method-to-clone-a-mysql-database/

Comment: Not so nice, if your Database contians some InnoDB tables. Those can break this way!

Comment: here is a much more complete answer I wrote based on what I learned since then:
http://verens.com/2016/05/11/quick-method-to-clone-a-mysql-database/

I've used that many times on quite large databases and it works every time

Answer (score 6):

```
mysql -u root -p < all.sql
```

will do

Answer (score 2):

From command line:

```
mysql -uroot < all.sql
```

ps. If you want to see what statement is executed right now you should `-v`.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -u root -p
```

that command will open the mysql interactive console, where you'd do this:

```
source all.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

execute the dump file from shell (dump file should contain the CREATE DATABASE syntax)

```
mysql -uroot < /path/to/file.sql
```

or execute from mysql

```
source /path/to/file.sql
```